# I have special characters in list and it breaks SikuliX

Tags: python-2.7, sikuli, sikuli-x

I try to get paths into list and everything is working just fine until I get special characters like `ä` or `ö`. In string they are represented as bytes for example `ä` is `\xe4`. If I use same Python script in Terminal I get all paths printed out correctly even though paths in list contain these bytes instead of actual letters.

Here is my code where I extract all the filenames:

```
def read_files(path):
    """
    Read all files in folder specified by path
    :param path: Path to folder which contents will be read
    :return: List of all files in folder specified by path
    """
    files = []
    for f in listdir(path):
        if isfile(join(path, f)):
            files.append(make_unicode(join(path, f)))
    return files

def make_unicode(string):
    if type(string) != unicode:
        string = string.decode('utf-8')
    return string
```

I don't have any idea where to go from now on. I have tried practically everything I possibly could find from Google. This is more of a SikuliX problem than Python, because Python code works just fine outside SikuliX.

I use Python 2.7 and SikuliX 1.1.1.

Comment: As far as I know, the core issue is the lack of good unicode support in SikuliX. If you are flexible with the tools and on Windows, you can use [SeeShell plus Python](https://github.com/A9T9/SeeShell/tree/master/Python) instead. It has full Unicode support.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 so it seems I have to just live with this lack of special characters. This lack of Unicode support is really annoying since it makes life a lot harder when making something with Nordics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this covered. Problem was, that `read_files(path)` function was called again later and when the `path` was unicode with special characters marked as bytes the whole thing broke. I changed my code in a fashion that this function was called only once and then I was able to work with special characters.